# Typescript inference, variance and redux.createStore

Tags: typescript

Whenever I pass a reducer to redux's `createStore`, the compiler somewhere is trying to assign `GenericAction :> MyAction` when, I guess, it should be doing the opposite `MyAction :> GenericAction`. Is there something I'm missing?

Edit: `strictFunctionTypes : false` disables the error, so it is variance-related.

Is there a workaround for that without disabling `strictFunctionTypes`?

I have cooked a simplified example below.

```
//test helpers
function _typ<T>(): T {
  return undefined as any
}
function _tryAssign<X extends Y, Y>(): any {}

//redux stub
type GenericAction = { type: string; [k: string]: any }
type Reducer<S> = (state: S, action: GenericAction) => S
type StoreCreator = <S>(reducer: Reducer<S>) => any

///my code
const createStore = _typ<StoreCreator>()
const initialState = { a: 1 }
type State = typeof initialState
type MyActions = {
  type: "A1"
  payload: {
    pl1: string
  }
}

const reducer = (state: State, actions: MyActions) => state
// Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'MyActions'.
createStore(reducer)

// Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'MyActions'.
_tryAssign<typeof reducer, Reducer<any>>()

//MyActions is assignable to Action
_tryAssign<MyActions, GenericAction>()
//Action is not assignable to MyActions
_tryAssign<GenericAction, MyActions>()
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide suggests the use of redux ^4.0, or enabling `strictFunctionTypes : false` if using redux 3.x.